# know the existence of files equal to a partial name + extention

Tags: php, pattern-matching, glob, directory-structure, file-search

I'm trying to have a filter, to see if a file exists or not, and how many are: I'm trying to pick up the script with as follows:

```
$list = glob($filepath.$filenamePartial'*'.$ext);
var_dump($list);
```

**Solved 1:**

```
$list   = glob($filepath.$FsisName.'_'.$count.'_'.'*'.$ext);
if (count($list) <= 0){
        $FFileUPL   = $filepath.$FsisName.'_'.$count.'_'.$FileDate.'.'.$ext;
        $event      =   move_uploaded_file($flTName, $FFileUPL);
    }else{
        echo 'this file Exist: '.$FsisName.'-'.$count.'-'.$FileDate.'.'.$ext.'<br>';
        $event  =   false;
    }
```

**How can i retrive the name file in the iteratos?**
**Solved 2:**

```
foreach($list as $fnames){
    $eFile['smg']       .= basename($fnames).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: So, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) didn't explain it well enough?

Comment: As a sidenote now there also exists [StackOverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank yea i have aupdate to it.

Comment: @WeaponX i don't know that you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
$list   = glob($filepath.$FsisName.'_'.$count.'_'.'*'.$ext);
if (count($list) <= 0){
        $FFileUPL   = $filepath.$FsisName.'_'.$count.'_'.$FileDate.'.'.$ext;
        $event      =   move_uploaded_file($flTName, $FFileUPL);
    }else{
        echo 'this file Exist: '.$FsisName.'-'.$count.'-'.$FileDate.'.'.$ext.'<br>';
        $event  =   false;
    }
foreach($list as $fnames){
    $eFile['smg']       .= basename($fnames).'<br>';
}
```